# php get missing value from array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have this is output from database in array
And need get missing value in this is exmaple is: **30001**, i have this code for get it:
I need fix this problem i try more functions and not have solution. Thanks

IDs

`Array ( [0] => 30000 ) Array ( [0] => 30002 ) Array ( [0] => 30003 )`

```
$field = array($ids);


   for($i=0;$i<count($field);$i++){
    if($field[$i] + 1 != $field[$i+1]){
      echo($field[$i] + 1 .' IS the missing number<br>');
    }
  }
```

ouptut is

```
30001 IS the missing number  -- ONLY THIS IS TRUE
30003 IS the missing number
30004 IS the missing number
```

thanks

Comment: Those are in three different arrays on top. Could you add `var_dump($field);` right after `$field = array($ids);` and add the results here so I can see what the structure of the array looks like?

Comment: Why not using `in_array` PHP function ? Put your values in an array and check if specific value is not in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have an array of rows coming back from your database query, where each row has an ID value, and the rows are sorted:

```
$rows = [
    [0 => 30000],
    [0 => 30002],
    [0 => 30003],
];
```

I suggest you need to consider pairs of entries that could be separated by one or more 'missing' IDs.  This could be done with a `while` loop, where we compare the ID of the `$currentRow` and the `$nextRow`, identifying all the 'missing' IDs in between using a `for` loop:

```
$currentRow = reset($rows);

while ($nextRow = next($rows)) {
    $idOfCurrentRow = reset($currentRow);
    $idOfNextRow = reset($nextRow);
    for ($id = $idOfCurrentRow + 1; $id < $idOfNextRow; $id++) {
        echo $id . ' IS the missing number<br>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $currentRow = $nextRow;
}
```

With the data above, the result is:

```
30001 IS the missing number<br>
```